# How to get the MAX count of a column for a certain id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trouble wording this into a clear title, so first let me clarify.

I have a table containing multiple columns, but only two relevant ones.

```
ID  ||  type
-------------
1   ||  5
1   ||  7
2   ||  6
2   ||  7
2   ||  7
2   ||  7
3   ||  5
```

What I want is the MAX number of occurance of the type 7 for any given ID (not an ID I enter myself, just any ID)

So for example, the result for the example table above would be 3 (3 type 7s for the same id).

Is there any simple way to go about doing this? I have a few ideas, but all seem terribly complicated and unnecessarily long, like doing separate queries for every single ID and comparing results.

Also, I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I simply couldn't  word my question well enough to find any relevant information.

Comment: Hmmm, why is this so hard? Where are your attempts so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be a subquery:

```
select max(cnt)
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      where type = 7
      group by id
     ) t;
```

But there is a clever way without a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from table t
where type = 7
group by id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `COUNT()` aggregate function along with `GROUP BY` clause like

```
select ID, count(type)
from table1
group by ID
order by count(type) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Beware that `ID` in the results might be a bit misleading in the event of a tie.